# Selecting and Formatting two columns into one in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I've been searching through the questions to find this one, and I can't seem to find it (I hope this isn't a duplicate)

How, in Oracle would I select two columns and show them together. Right now I would like them formatted like this:

```
select CONCAT(NAME, ' (', DESCRIPTION, ')') as display_value, ID as return_value 
  from TABLE_NAME
 order by 1
```

But I get an invalid number of arguments error. That isn't my issue, I would like to know if it's possible to do what I'm trying to do.

And that is to have it display:
Name (Description)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

concat accepts only 2 arguments, you need to use something like that:

```
select
    CONCAT(NAME, concat(' (', concat(DESCRIPTION, ')'))) as display_value,
    ID as return_value
from TABLE_NAME
order by 1
```

or another syntax:

```
select
    NAME || ' (' || DESCRIPTION || ')' as display_value,
    ID as return_value
from TABLE_NAME
order by 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you simply need this:

```
select NAME || ' (' || DESCRIPTION || ')' as display_value
```